# References in comments?

Tags: discussion

I did some ballpark approximations as a sanity check. I wasn't sure if those are correct so I posted them in a comment. Someone commented that I should've given references for the numbers used.

Since comments are so limited, is it appropriate to ask for references?

Comment: If you want people to take your numbers / information seriously, you should give references.  But comments can go away at any time.

Comment: I think what Organic is trying to say is that at some point you have to decide whether you can make an answer or not. If not, then you have to decide whether it is worth your time to justify your information to doubters. There's certainly nothing wrong with someone asking you for references, but neither are you obliged to provide them. However, you can't expect anyone to take you seriously either.

Comment: If you were not prepared to do the work to write a full answer (nothing wrong with that) citing references would give other people a start in writing a proper answer. But as called2voyage said, you don't have to. A comment can just be a pointer to further investigation.